# Is there a way to add up amount depending on what is in a certain position on a text file?

Tags: python, if-statement

***I have tried***

totalValue = 0
    bagsChecked = 0

```
for x in range(len(volunteerList)):
    record = volunteerList[x]

    if record[1] == "1 pence":
        amount = 1.00
    elif record[1] == "2 pence":
        amount = 1.00
    elif record[1] == "5 pence":
        amount = 5.00
    elif record[1] == "10 pence":
        amount = 5.00
    elif record[1] == "20 pence":
        amount = 10.00
    elif record[1] == "50 pence":

        amount = 10.00
    elif record[1] == "1 pound":
        amount = 20.00
    else:
        amount = 20.00

    totalValue = totalValue + amount
    bagsChecked = bagsChecked + 1

    print("Bags checked: ",bagsChecked)
    print("Total Value: ",totalValue)'''
```

***Is there a way that I can fix this so that it displays an accurate number of bags checked and total value.***

Comment: I have several different functions and in my first function the user enters their name, a coin type and coin weight. The program then adds these details to a text file along with yes or no depending on if the user entered the correct weight for the coin type. In the second function,the one shown above, I want the program to read the coin type and then set an amount for it depending on the coin type. I then want all of the different amounts to add up and be displayed. I also want the program to show the amount of bags that have been checked. So it will need to count the amount of lines in the..

Comment: ...text file and then display this as the number of bags checked.

Comment: @chintan thakrar

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure this will run because I don't know what your data looks like, but you could try something like this:

```
total_value = 0
total_bags = 0

for rec in volunteerList:

    if "pence" in rec[1]:
        total_value += float(rec[1].split[' '][0])
    if "pound" in rec[1]:
        total_value += 20 * float(rec[1].split[' '][0])

    total_bags += 1

    print("Bags checked: {}".format(total_bags))
    print("Total Value: {}".format(total_value))
```

This assumes each entry in `volunteerList` is a string which contains either "pence" or "pound". Then we split the string and keep the numerical portion for our tally.

Comment: Would this still work if the items in the text file are numbers e.g.1 pence?

Comment: if the line contains the word pence, it must be a string, like "1 pence". If the line is just "1", you don't need the ```.split``` function and can just do ```total_value += float(rec[1])```

Comment: Kind of. It has helped me understand the way I need to go about it.